# how to use django login

Tags: python, django

I have the following code and I get an error saying: "the User object has no attribute POST"

```
def login (request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(user)
            return render(request, 'base_in/base_in.html', {})
        else:
            return render(request, 'signupapp/error.html', {'message':'the acount is not active'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'signupapp/error.html', {'message':'username and password is incorrect'})
```

I also tried this code and got another error: "login() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

```
def login (request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(user)
            return render(request, 'base_in/base_in.html', {})
        else:
            return render(request, 'signupapp/error.html', {'message':'the acount is not active'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'signupapp/error.html', {'message':'username and password is incorrect'})
```

What am I doing wrong? Based on django tutorials it should work properly:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happened is you try to call `login` of `from django.contrib.auth`, but you are also defining your own function called `login()`, you have a kind of name conflict here.

You should rename that to something else, e.g. `login_view()`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login_view(request): # If you call it login,
                         # you get conflict with login imported aove
     # The rest of your code here
     # now if you call login(user), it will use the correct one,
     # i.e. the one imported from django.contrib.auth
```

If you prefer not to rename, you can import Django's `login` under a different name, e.g.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

# Then use auth_login(user) in your code
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise adding a login form first

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
   username = forms.CharField()
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)#hides password on input
```

then

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
.
.


def user_log(request):
  #if you add request.method=='POST' is it a bug i dont know y
  if request.method:
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cleandata=form.cleaned_data
        #authenticate checks if credentials exists in db
        user=authenticate(username=cleandata['username'],
                          password=cleandata['password'])
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("your template")
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("your templlate")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login")
    else:
        form=LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Can you explain why is it better to add a log in form while I can use django.contrib.auth.models.User and have a log in template?

Comment: @bakkal answer is best.But similar to you i faced the same problem thats how i solved it.