# Login with both username and password in django 2.2.5

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-authentication, django-login

**How can we login with username or password in Django site and Django Admin pages?**

I tried by creating custom user model and making email field as username field but I can don't want to login with either username or email.

I want to use any of both any time to login.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use django login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751775/how-to-use-django-login)

Comment: check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44972983/allowing-both-email-and-username-login-in-django-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 
{
from django.db.models import Q

Example:

```
from django.db.models import Q
user = "username/eamil"
password= "your password"
user_check = models.YourModelName.objects.filter((Q(email = user)|Q(username = user)), password = password)
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  When posting code, paste it, select it, and then click the `{}` widget to render it as text.